# Trying to hide image styling, if no image is present - Advanced Custom Fields images

Tags: css, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

I have styled my images on my Content Page Template to have borders, backgrounds and box-shadow. If I don't use the optional image field and leave it empty, it leaves the css styling with a small box. I have been trying to hide the entire .content-img class if there is no image present. The code below works fine for rendering the images if they are present. How to hide it if no image is present.

`<?php the_field('top_headline'); ?></h1>`
    `<div class="content-top"><?php the_field('content_top'); ?></div>`
    `<div class="content-img"><?php`
`$image = get_field('content_image');`
`$size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)`
`if( $image ) {`
    `echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );`
`} ?>`

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I took care of it using CSS instead of in the array. instead of using the css class `.content-img` (which is my parent div), I added the image to the class `.content-img img` and if no image is present, the css wont show.